# How to avoid using dot notation to access default exported class instance when requiring in generated commonjs bundle

Tags: typescript, commonjs

I am exporting a class instance in a TypeScript file like so:

**index.ts**

```
export { myClient } from './my-client.ts'
```

**my-client.ts**

```
class myClient {
}

export const myClient =  new myClient();
```

I'm then compiling this down to commonjs in es5 format, and when I go to use this in node, I have to access it like so:

```
const myClient = require('myclient').myClient;
```

Whilst this works, is there a way I can require in and use my class without having to use the `.myClient` notation?

**Update**

I tried changing the export of my class instance like so in my TS files:

**index.ts**

```
export { default as myClient } from './my-client.ts'
```

**my-client.ts**

```
class myClient {
}

const myClient =  new myClient();
export default myClient;
```

But I am still having to access like so in my node application:

```
const myClient = require('myclient').myClient;
```

Comment: Shouldn't exporting as default do the trick?

Comment: Oh gosh, I feel dumb now

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic - unfortunately that did not work, see my update on my question. Unless I am attempting this incorrectly?

Comment: First, you are reexporting the default export as a named export, hence it does not work as you'd expect. You have to rewrite `index.ts` in such a way, that myClient is once again reexported as default. Furthermore I don't understand why you are refering to `require` and CommonJS syntax in the first place which causes issues with interop as you just experienced. Please have a look at this: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html

Comment: Thanks, I just want to make sure when I compile my TS down it can be used by as many consumers as possible, although I'm mainly wanting to target nodejs and browser module bundlers. I'm using webpack after compiling down with the TS compiler to generate a UMD bundle. Sorry if I'm not making sense here, I'm a bit new to module formats. Are you able to suggest the refactor I would need to do in the top level index.ts? Thanks for your time.